# Grails 2 forked mode doesn't deploy my app

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm trying to use Grails new forked mode. I enabled it in BuildConfig.groovy file using

```
grails.project.fork.run = true
```

and now the tomcat server starts in "detached mode" as expected, but my application is not deployed.
I also configured an external directory where I put the war of my application, like this:

```
grails.project.autodeploy.dir = "../mywar"
```

but nothing changed.

Is there anything else I should do to configure forked mode?

Comment: Did you mean `grails.project.fork.run=true`?

Comment: What do you mean with "is not deployed"? When you hit the url of your application what happens?

Comment: I mean that nothing happens navigating to the url of my app (I get a white page). Nothing is printed on the log (the server starts in a couple of seconds...my app is quite big and it takes several seconds to initialize). If lauched normally (not forked) the app starts without problems.